# Unable to access anydesk security section in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, remote-desktop, ubuntu-22.04

I have installed ubuntu 22.04, then tried to download anydesk. But the problem is after installing anydesk when i try to access the security section everytrime after giving my password it still ca not be accesible.

I have tried installing libganpox package manually, even after that anydesk is not working. what should i do?

Comment: You can apply the same fix available here,
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478969/realvnc-server-doesnt-run-on-ubuntu-22-04/1488777?noredirect=1#comment2637732_1488777